# Can a token issued on Stellar determine its own transaction fees?

Tags: token, assets, fees

Would a token that plans to take an additional percentage Lumens for transaction fees be possible to create on the existing Stellar network?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The maximum you can do is to control who is allowed to purchase your token with [AUTHORIZATION REQUIRED](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/assets.html#controlling-asset-holders) flag.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!  So it would need to run on its own network entirely? Isn’t it possible to fork the code to create this?

Comment: You don't have to fork anything in order to run your personal network. All you need is to specify another passphrase and arbitrary ports (you might want to run Mainnet and your private Network on the same servers, otherwise leave default ports). Once the network is started, you may change transaction fees. And all lumens on this network initially belong to you. See the configuration example [here](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/docs/stellar-core_standalone.cfg).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Imagine I Want to Tokenize Shares/Commodities but Not Build My Own Exchange to Allow Commissions.(Like Kinesis) But Rather Collect 0.5% of Every SDEX Transaction of My Issued Tkns. The Seller Sells Bob 100 Tkns & Bob Receives 99.5; The Issuer of Tkns Receives 0.5 Tkns.

I'm Thinking of a Way Some Investment House(Interactive Brokers) Would be Incentivised to Issue Equity backed Tokens to be Traded on SDEX. Those Starting on this Task Are Establishing Their Own Exchanges That Do Not Contribute to Stellar Volume & Their Tokens Will NOT be Accessible on SDEX / StellarX / Lobstr Wallet etc.